# How to save date retrieved from datepicker into database in windows phone 7?

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, datepicker, windows-phone-7.1

How do I save a date retrieved form the datepicker into the database?.I have added the toolkit window.phone.control.toolkit and added this line in my xaml page.

```
 <toolkit:DatePicker ValueChanged="DatePicker_ValueChanged" Margin="296,0,0,552" />
```

and this is my event handler where i get the choosen date, but how do i pass the date value into my database, to save it in my date coloumn?

```
private void DatePicker_ValueChanged(object sender, DateTimeValueChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var date = e.NewDateTime;
    }
```

Im using this code to add items to my database where I have 2 columns Studentname(type string) and date(DateTime)

```
using (StudentDataContext Expdb = new StudentDataContext(strConnectionString))
        {
            Student StudentInfo = new Student
            {

               StudentName = textBox.Text.ToString(),

               StudentDate = ????


            };

            db.StudentInfo.InsertOnSubmit(newStudent);
            db.SubmitChanges();
```

what code do i write in order to save the date chosen by the user to be stored in the table? Im new to windows phone programming and silverlight, please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following code to get the date time

```
Student StudentInfo = new Student
{
     StudentName = textBox.Text.ToString(),
     StudentDate = (DateTime)datePicker1.Value;
};
db.StudentInfo.InsertOnSubmit(newStudent);
db.SubmitChanges();
```

Here `datePicker1` is the name of the DatePicker control

Comment: Please close the question.